# Github Copilot Explain this chat showing up on top of screen

Tags: github-copilot

Im not seeing much rhyme or reason as to why this behavior suddenly happened after updating to v1.141.0 - but now when I have a chat in the side panel and ask "whats this" (Right click terminal message - select explain this)

It wants to treat it like a separate instance of copilot at the top center of my vscode.
[image]

My settings.json is barren of customization.
Co pilot is setup for workspaces to leverage code completion suggestions.
You will notice the used@workspace in the side panel chat:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is the open in chat view button that makes this really easy.
[image]